# OFFIS DICOM - dcmdump v3.6.0 - (0002,0010) Transfer Syntax UID

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

I use OFFIS DICOM dcmdump tool to extract information from a DICOM image:
http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/dcmdump.html

I use `dcmdump.exe  -M -L +Qn` to dump the DICOM information.

Output looks like

## Dicom-File-Format

```
# Dicom-Meta-Information-Header
# Used TransferSyntax: Little Endian Explicit
(0002,0000) UL 164                                      #   4, 1 FileMetaInformationGroupLength
(0002,0001) OB 00\01                                    #   2, 1 FileMetaInformationVersion
(0002,0002) UI =DigitalXRayImageStorageForPresentation  #  28, 1 MediaStorageSOPClassUID
(0002,0003) UI [1.2.826.0.1.3680043.2.876.8598.1.4.0.20160428091911.2.2] #  56, 1 MediaStorageSOPInstanceUID
(0002,0010) UI =JPEGLSLossless                          #  22, 1 TransferSyntaxUID
(0002,0012) UI [1.2.276.0.64]                           #  12, 1 ImplementationClassUID
```

Why did dcmdump translate (0002,0010) to the value `JPEGLSLossless` instead of `1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.80` ?

Is there any switch to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

dcmdump does so because it translates well known UIDs to human readable meanings by default.

The parameter you are searching for to change this behavior is -Un (--no-uid-names)